# OAuth2 token returned from Office 365 doesn't contain a preffered_username claim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, office365api, oauth-2.0

I followed [this tutorial](http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2142) and have gotten to the point where I am decoding the returned token, and extracting the email address (which should be stored in the *preferred_username* property), ie, the following code:

```
decoded_token = Base64.urlsafe_decode64(encoded_token)
jwt = JSON.parse(decoded_token)
email = jwt['preferred_username']
```

The problem is that the object returned doesn't contain this property, what I do get back is similar to below:

```
{  
   "ver":"2.0",
   "iss":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad/v2.0",
   "aud":"0ab6433e-84fc-469b-8c72-41f7a0241a61",
   "exp":1458142389,
   "iat":1458055989,
   "at_hash":"0OYaLKpTTdHNBrQNOqwQ0Q",
   "sub":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC1TrOaOmvInYrFAyrQjlFI",
   "tid":"9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad"
}
```

A quick glance at [the spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) indicates I am getting the correct object back from Office 365, as *preferred_username* is mentioned as a potential claim, but it isn't in the object I get back.

It's possible I'm not calling the *get_token* function with the correct parameters, but [the documentation for the library is pretty sparse](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2), so I can't really tell.

[I have raised an issue on Github.](https://github.com/jasonjoh/o365-tutorial/issues/6)

Is this an error on the Office 365 end, an error with the tutorial, or am I doing something wrong myself?

Comment: You could us `fetch`. For more info http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/jasonjoh/o365-tutorial/issues/6) by Jason Johnston from Microsoft (author of the tutorial):

> The Azure team deployed a breaking change to their v2 auth endpoint, which is causing the preferred_username to not be present. You need to add profile to the SCOPES array in auth_helper.rb. I'll post an update to the tutorial after the Build conference.

The SCOPES array in *auth_helper.rb* now looks like so:

```
SCOPES = [ 'openid', 'https://outlook.office.com/mail.read', 'profile' ]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 1):

I am try to reproduce this issue using normal HTTP request however I could get the **preferred_username** property successfully.

As far as I know, we can get this property only when we specific the **openid** scope in the request. To narrow down this issue, I suggest that you trying use Fiddler or Postman without Ruby.

Here is the test using web browser and Fiddler to get the id token for your reference:

1. Register the app in the portal using Office 365 account( which you can refer to the tutorial)
2. Get the auth code in a web broswer via the link below:
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={ClientID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={RedirectURL}&response_mode=query&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.read%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.send%20**openid**&state=12345
3. Replace the auth code from preview request and using Fiddler to post the request to get the tokens:

   POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
   grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={ClientID}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.read%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.send%20**openid**&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55065%2F&client_secret={ClientSecret}&code={AuthCode}
4. Decode the ID token from the link below:

   https://jwt.io/

Then I could get the preferred_username property from the ID token successfully.